# Symfony Different Validation for different usage cases on same entity

Tags: php, image, validation, symfony

So I have a Document Entity that stores file uploads (currently only Images) that is used all over the project which is a blog. Now for the article I want to be able to upload and select an Image that basically has little to no restriction apart from file size, but for a category I want to only be able to use Images that are square or not landscape and not portrait.

The Document Entity looks like this

```
class Document
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $path;

private $webPath;

private $filename;

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Document
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return Document
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}

public function setFullFilename()
{
    $this->filename = $this->id . '.' . $this->path;
}

public function getFilename()
{
    return $this->filename;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    //return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir(). '/' . $this->path;
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/';
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'bundles/pgblog/images/uploads';
}

private $file;

private $temp;

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;

    if(is_file($this->getAbsolutePath()))
    {
        $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    }
    else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }
}

public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function preUpload()
{
    if(null !== $this->getFile())
    {
        $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();

        $this->setMimetype();
        $this->setSize();
        /*
        $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->path = $filename . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        */
    }
}

public function upload()
{
    if(null === $this->getFile())
    {
        return;
    }

    if(isset($this->temp))
    {
        unlink($this->temp);
        $this->temp = null;
    }

    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->id . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension());

    $this->file = null;
}

public function storeFilenameForRemove()
{
    $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
}

public function removeUpload()
{
    if(isset($this->temp))
    {
        unlink($this->temp);
    }
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $mimetype;


/**
 * Set mimetype
 *
 * @param string $mimetype
 * @return Document
 */
public function setMimetype()
{
    $this->mimetype = $this->getFile()->getMimeType();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mimetype
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getMimetype()
{
    return $this->mimetype;
}
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $size;


/**
 * Set size
 *
 * @param integer $size
 * @return Document
 */
public function setSize()
{
    $this->size = $this->getFile()->getSize();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get size
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getSize()
{
    return $this->size;
}
```

}

I use seperate forms for file upload and article/category creation. When creating an article or category, a file can be chosen from a list of currently all Files

Here the form type for Article

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{

   ...

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('text')
        ->add('tags')
        ->add('category')
        ->add('image')
    ;
}

...
}
```

and the article entity

```
class Article
{
...

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param \Acme\UtilBundle\Entity\Document $image
 * @return Article
 */
public function setImage(\PG\BlogBundle\Entity\Document $image = null)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return \Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Document 
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}
}
```

`Article` is related to `Document` via a unidirectional many to one relationship

```
manyToOne:
    image:
        targetEntity: Document
        joinColumn:
            name: document_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

So in the form the files can be set by a select. For the article this is just fine, since I want to be able to use any image as an attachment, but for the categories I want only the files that are square as I said earlier.
I thought about using validation for the category image, but since the Image is selected by a select, the actual data is just a string (the file name given on the upload form) and not the image it self so the validation returns the error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Category::setImage() must be an instance of Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Document, string given...
```

So my question is, how do I restrict the Image options in the category form to only square images and how do I validate this properly?

The reason I only want to use square Images for category is so I can display a nice symmetric list of all the cateogries by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Store the image dimensions in your document entity (length, width).

That way when fetching the document collection for category forms you can filter image documents where length == width, so only display appropriate documents.

For validation, you have a number of options, the best place to start would be [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html). In your place I'd look into [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups).

Comment: Wow that answer is surprisingly simple.
But is there a solution that doesn't 'limit' the Document entity to Images only? I know I didn't really put that in my question. Currently my Document entity only holds images because I'm not using it for anything else but I'm planning on using in for every type of files on the entire website.